# New Raspberry Pi User

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am new to this forum and Python and in need of so help. I am building a project on a Raspberry Pi for a motion senor night light. I have the code working with the exception that I get trapped in the nested while loop.
The goal of this build is when the photoresistor detects darkness it will enable the motion sensor to detect motion. If motion is sensed while the photoresistor is detecting darkness the light will come on. I have attached the code below.

```
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from gpiozero import LightSensor
from time import sleep

red_led = LED(17)
pir = MotionSensor(4)
green_led = LED(21)
sensor = LightSensor(23)

red_led.off()
green_led.off()

while True:
    sensor.wait_for_light()
    print("Dark Mode")
    green_led.on()   
        
    while True:
        pir.wait_for_motion()
        print("Motion Detected")
        red_led.on()    
        pir.wait_for_no_motion()
        red_led.off()
        print("Motion Stopped")
              
    sensor.wait_for_dark()
    print("Light Mode")
    green_led.off()
```

Comment: Your ‘while True:’ loops will loop forever. That is what they are used for. It sounds like you need to test for a condition to exit the inner loop.

Comment: You never `break` the inner `while True` loop. Why do you expect it to exit?

Comment: If those are all blocking APIs, then I'm afraid you will have to use threads.  One thread will monitor the light sensor, one thread will monitor the motion detector.  I'll post an example below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible design.  This is untested.  You'll probably want to have a delay before shutting off the light.

```
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from gpiozero import LightSensor
from time import sleep
import threading

red_led = LED(17)
pir = MotionSensor(4)
green_led = LED(21)
sensor = LightSensor(23)

red_led.off()
green_led.off()

daylight = True

def lightSensorThread():
    global daylight
    daylight = True
    while True:
        sensor.wait_for_light()
        green_led.on()   
        daylight = True
        print( "Light mode" )
                  
        sensor.wait_for_dark()
        green_led.off()
        daylight = False
        print("Dark Mode")

def motionSensor():
    light = False
    while True:
        pir.wait_for_motion()
        print("Motion Detected")
        red_led.on()    
        if not daylight:
            # Turn the light on here
            light = True
        pir.wait_for_no_motion()
        print("Motion Stopped")
        red_led.off()
        if light:
            # Turn the light off here.
            light = False

sense = threading.Thread(target=lightSensorThread)
sense.start()
motionSensor()
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this. I prefer this method so that the light sensor is always being monitored.